# Variable keeps getting set to 1 at the end of recursion method

Tags: java, class, recursion

EDIT: Got it working. Still not sure what the weird issue was, but I think it had to do with the fact that I had a loop and recursion.

Comment: You mix recursion and loop here, choose one of them

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the question. but you don't need both, a while loop and recursion. Recursion alone is sufficient here. Use a simple if statement to stop recursion when the number is fully printed.

Note that recursion simplifies putting the digits in the right order here -- with a while loop, you'd need to reverse them somehow...

```
public static void printInBinary (int num) {
  int div = num % 2;
  int rem = num / 2;
  if (rem > 0) {
    printInBinary(rem);
  }
  System.out.print(div);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'm still curious as to what was happening with my original problem though. When I ran the program, num would eventually equal 0 and skip the while loop. Then it would go to the next closed curly bracket (looking in debug) and set num back to 1 which would activate the while loop all over again.

Comment: @DRMG It's hard to check now because you seem to have removed the code fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is continuously going because your num-- isn't in the loop, so the number never changes.

```
    public static void printInBinary (int num)
{

    int div = (Integer)num%2;
    int rem = (Integer)num/2;


    while (num >= 1)
    {
        System.out.print(div);
        printInBinary(rem);
        num--;//Moved here
    }

    //removed from here

}
```

Comment: The num-- doesn't do anything. As I stated in the op, I just put it there to try and stop it. Moving it there, getting rid of it, nothing changes.